# How to determine the difference between the values of two columns?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Let's say I have such table in `PostgreSQL` (version 11) database:

```
| ID | PERSONAL_PERCENT | GLOBAL_PERCENT |
|----|------------------|----------------|
| 1  | 50,6544401544    | 52,5519848771  |
| 1  | 25,0000          | 52,5519848771  |
| 1  | 61,9117647059    | 52,5519848771  |
```

I am trying to write SQL query which would return result set with new column. In my case that column called `COLOR`. The value of that colomn depends on the values of the colomns as `PERSONAL_PERCENT` and `GLOBAL_PERCENT`.

1) If `PERSONAL_PERCENT` is greater than `GLOBAL_PERCENT` by 5 percent there must be GREEN color. For example `61,9117647059` value of `PERSONAL_PERCENT` column is 5 percent higher than `52,5519848771` value of `GLOBAL_PERCENT` column. For thats why COLOR column has GREEN value.

2) If `PERSONAL_PERCENT` is less than `GLOBAL_PERCENT` by 5 percent there must be RED color. For example `25,0000` value of `PERSONAL_PERCENT` column is 5  percent lower than `52,5519848771` value of `GLOBAL_PERCENT` column. For thats why COLOR column has RED value.

3) If `PERSONAL_PERCENT` is less than `GLOBAL_PERCENT` and the difference between 1 and 5 percent there must be YELLOW color. For example `50,6544401544` value of `PERSONAL_PERCENT` column is less not more 5 percent than `52,5519848771` value of `GLOBAL_PERCENT` column. For thats why COLOR column has YELLOW value.

I want such final result with new column:

```
| ID | PERSONAL_PERCENT | GLOBAL_PERCENT | COLOR  |
|----|------------------|----------------|--------|
| 1  | 50,6544401544    | 52,5519848771  | YELLOW |
| 1  | 25,0000          | 52,5519848771  | RED    |
| 1  | 61,9117647059    | 52,5519848771  | GREEN  |
```

Comment: Share the query you've come up with. Don't just ask answer for your assignments

Comment: FYI, this is typically a front-end or, at a stretch, middleware function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
       (case when personal_percent < global_percent * 0.95 then 'RED'
             when personal_percent > global_percent * 0.95 then 'GREEN'
             else 'YELLOW'
        end) as color
from t;
```